# app closes after pyinstaller Mac Os

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller, agent

Problem is when i try to open app converted from my Python script into Mac app with pyinstaller, it closes in a second.

I'm using pyinstaller with flags `-w -F` like this
`sudo pyinstaller client.py -w -F`
so I've got 2 files in a dist folder

```
client
```

which is exec file. And

```
client.app
```

so when i try to run exec file - everything is ok, but when I clicked client.app I've seen icon in dock for a second and then it disappeared. But if I go into client.app/Contents/MacOS/  and run client it runs ok again.

I thought problem could be in Info.plist file but i'm not shure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict><key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>client</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>client</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>client</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>MacOS/client</string>
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>icon-windowed.icns</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>0.0.0</string>
<key>LSBackgroundOnly</key>
<string>0</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

client - is console program. So how can i fix the problem with client.app?